# How do I install ros-hydro-ros-comm on Arm?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-hydro, gumstix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to install ros-hydro-ros-comm I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-ros-comm : Depends: ros-hydro-roslisp but it is not going to be installed
```

I am using the Arm instruction on the Wiki with sources at:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ahendrix-mirror/ubuntu raring main
```

So how do I resolve this? I noticed that rostopic did not exist and that I was missing this packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121596/how-do-i-install-ros-hydro-ros-comm-on-arm?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ARM repositories have moved to http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros . Please update your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list appropriately.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0